# row for statistics comparing more than one column in dataframe

Tags: python

I'm trying to add an extra row that shows the statistics for all of the zones. It should not be the sum of the columns but a comparison of all. 
F.ex. the maximum value between all zones is 8.

```
df = data.describe(include='all').transpose()


in:
       zone1  zone2  zone3  zone4
    0   -1.0    2.0    3.0    4.0
    1    5.0    6.0    1.0    8.0
    2    3.0   -1.0   -1.0    6.0
    3    2.0    3.0    4.0    5.0

out:
           count  mean       std  min   25%  50%   75%  max
    zone1    4.0  2.25  2.500000 -1.0  1.25  2.5  3.50  5.0
    zone2    4.0  2.50  2.886751 -1.0  1.25  2.5  3.75  6.0
    zone3    4.0  1.75  2.217356 -1.0  0.50  2.0  3.25  4.0
    zone4    4.0  5.75  1.707825  4.0  4.75  5.5  6.50  8.0
```

I have searched the internet for some hours without luck. Can someone please help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to melt the entire `df` to a single colunm, and then describe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'zone1': [-1, 5, 3, 2], 'zone2': [2, 6, -1, 3], 'zone3': [3, 1, -1, 4], 'zone4': [4, 8, 6, 5]})
data.melt()['value'].describe()
```

Output:

```
count    16.00000
mean      3.06250
std       2.67005
min      -1.00000
25%       1.75000
50%       3.00000
75%       5.00000
max       8.00000
Name: value, dtype: float64
```